# Opening and displaying images from directory

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a downloaded image from a temporary directory

I've tried other ways on how to do it but i can't seem to get it to work.
In the below example I've tried with Image.asset() but that won't work either because it can't be assigned to Image Provider.

```dart
var dir = Directory.systemTemp;
final String name = data['file_name'];
final String path = "${dir.path}/$name";


BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: Image.asset(path)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                offset: new Offset(offset / 2, offset),
                blurRadius: blur,
              )
            ]),
```

I just want my image to be displayed from custom directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of this package, you can get the path the path temporary and from directory [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider)

This is the way how you can utilize this:

```
final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String imgDir = dir + "/your_directory";
```

In order to find files from the above directory, you can use [listSync](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Directory/listSync.html) package.

```
final myDir = new Directory(imgDir);
List<FileSystemEntity> _images;
_images = myDir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: false);
```

I guess that'd solve your issue. Thanks

Comment: it turns out u solved another issue of mine :D what I had the problem with here is actually displaying an image from that directory

Comment: That's great. :D